# XML parser for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, json, browser, parsing

I am looking for a good JavaScript library for parsing XML data. It should be much easier to use than the built-in [XML DOM parsers](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp) bundled with the browsers.

I got spoiled a bit working with JSON and am looking forward to something on similar lines for XML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this.  Here is a good example:

(EDIT: Note - the following blog seems to have gone away.)

http://blog.reindel.com/2007/09/24/jquery-and-xml-revisited/

There are also lots and lots of good examples in the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) documentation:

http://www.webmonkey.com/tutorial/Easy_XML_Consumption_using_jQuery?oldid=20032

EDIT: Due to the blog for my primary example going away, I wanted to add another example that shows the basics and helps with namespace issues:

http://www.zachleat.com/web/selecting-xml-with-javascript/

Comment: The reindel link has been abducted.

Comment: Here's a mirror of the blog: http://web.archive.org/web/20080110113712/http://blog.reindel.com/2007/09/24/jquery-and-xml-revisited/

Comment: Maybe you can include a printout of the blog as a PDF attachment to the answer? I'd get rid of the "EDIT" notes because they make the text less clear. I'd just remove dead links and replace them with live links

Comment: Did [the meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492) start here?

Answer (score 48):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author if the open-source [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) library which *may* be suitable for the task.

---

A couple of years ago I was also looking for a good XML<->JSON parsing/serialization library for JavaScript. I needed to process XML documents conforming to rather complex XML Schemas. In Java, I routinely use [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) for the task so I was looking for something similar:

> [Is there a JavaScript API for XML binding - analog to JAXB for Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819192/is-there-a-javascript-api-for-xml-binding-analog-to-jaxb-for-java)

I failed to find such a tool back then.

So I wrote [**Jsonix**](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) which I consider to be a JAXB analog for JavaScript.

You may find [Jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix) suitable, if you're interested in the following features:

- XML<->JSON conversion is based on a **declaraive mapping** between XML and JSON structures
- This **mapping** can be **generated from an XML Schema** or written manually
- **Bidirectional** - supports parsing as well as serialization (or unmarshalling/marshalling in other terms).
- Support **elements**, **attributes** and also considers **namespaces** defined in the XML document.
- Strictly typed.
- Strictly structured.
- Support almost all of the **XML Schema built-in types** (including special types like `QName`).
- Works in **browsers** as well as **Node.js**, also compatible to [**RequireJS**](http://requirejs.org/)/[**AMD**](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) (also to [`amdefine`](https://github.com/jrburke/amdefine) in Node.js)
- Has [extensive documentation](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/JSNX/User+Guide).

However, Jsonix *may be an overkill*, if your XML is rather simple, does not have an XML Schema or if you're not interested in strict typing or structures. Check your requirements.

**Example**

Try it [in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lexi/LP3DC/).

You can take a [purchase order schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#po.xsd) and generate a mapping for it using the following command:

```
java -jar node_modules/jsonix/lib/jsonix-schema-compiler-full.jar
  -d mappings -p PO purchaseorder.xsd
```

You'll get a `PO.js` file which describes mappings between XML and JavaScript structures. Here's a snippet from this mapping file to give you an impression:

```javascript
var PO = {
    name: 'PO',
    typeInfos: [{
        localName: 'PurchaseOrderType',
        propertyInfos: [{
            name: 'shipTo',
            typeInfo: 'PO.USAddress'
        }, {
            name: 'billTo',
            typeInfo: 'PO.USAddress'
        }, {
            name: 'comment'
        }, {
            name: 'orderDate',
            typeInfo: 'Calendar',
            type: 'attribute'
        }, ...]
    }, {
        localName: 'USAddress',
        propertyInfos: [ ... ]
    }, ...],
    elementInfos: [{
        elementName: 'purchaseOrder',
        typeInfo: 'PO.PurchaseOrderType'
    }, ... ]
};
```

Having this mapping file you can parse the [XML](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/blob/master/fiddles/po/demo.response.xml):

```javascript
// First we construct a Jsonix context - a factory for unmarshaller (parser)
// and marshaller (serializer)
var context = new Jsonix.Context([PO]);

// Then we create a unmarshaller
var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

// Unmarshal an object from the XML retrieved from the URL
unmarshaller.unmarshalURL('po.xml',
    // This callback function will be provided
    // with the result of the unmarshalling
    function (unmarshalled) {
        // Alice Smith
        console.log(unmarshalled.value.shipTo.name);
        // Baby Monitor
        console.log(unmarshalled.value.items.item[1].productName);
    });
```

Or serialize your JavaScript object as XML:

```javascript
// Create a marshaller
var marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

// Marshal a JavaScript Object as XML (DOM Document)
var doc = marshaller.marshalDocument({
    name: {
        localPart: "purchaseOrder"
    },
    value: {
        orderDate: { year: 1999, month: 10, day: 20 },
        shipTo: {
            country: "US",
            name: "Alice Smith",
            street: "123 Maple Street",
            city: "Mill Valley",
            state: "CA",
            zip: 90952
        },
        billTo: { /* ... */ },
        comment: 'Hurry, my lawn is going wild!',
        items: { /* ... */ }
    }
});
```

You can try it [in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lexi/LP3DC/) to see how it works in practice.

---

**Additional disclaimer:** this answer is high-voted because of the [following discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276942/correcting-my-own-spam-answer-is-it-fine-now) on meta. *So please be aware of the "meta-effect".* High votes here do not necessarily mean that Jsonix is good, applicable or recommended by the community. Do not be mislead by the high votes.

Answer (score 2):

If your XML is in a simple format you may look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and the [XML to JSON plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xml2json) or the [xmlObjectifier](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/xmlObjectifier).

For a straight parser you may want to look at [XML for <SCRIPT>](http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [XML for SCRIPT](http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/). I have to admit, that I have never used it personally, but I have heard/read a few good things about it.

Give it a try and maybe share your experience here?