# Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-browser, cross-platform

Are there any cross-browser / cross-platform ways to parse XML files in Javascript?

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-in-javascript

Comment: Isnt' this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript/8412989#8412989 ?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83405/xml-parser-for-javascript/83584#83584) was the earliest request for a cross-platform XML parser, but it was closed for being off-topic as it asked for an off-site resource (just as this question was).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The following will work in all major browsers, including IE 6:

```js
var parseXml;

if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" &&
       new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    throw new Error("No XML parser found");
}
```

Example usage:

```js
var xml = parseXml("<foo>Stuff</foo>");
alert(xml.documentElement.nodeName);
```

Live demo:

```js
var parseXml;

if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
    };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" &&
       new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
        var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
        return xmlDoc;
    };
} else {
    throw new Error("No XML parser found");
}

var xml = parseXml("<foo>Stuff</foo>");
document.body.innerHTML = "Root element: " + xml.documentElement.nodeName;
```

Comment: This works, except in IE9 in standards mode. In IE9 standards mode to correct the issue, you just need to reform your initial if statement to be something like: if (window.DOMParser && typeof XMLDocument !== "undefined")

Comment: @GotDibbs: Really? The above example works fine for me in IE 9 standards.

Comment: Yep. Not sure if there's some other setting getting in the way here, but the moment I go into the dev toolbar and switch the browser mode to IE9 and document mode to IE9 standards it bombs without that additional check.

Comment: @GotDibbs: I know it's been a while, but here's a jsFiddle that works fine for me in IE 9 standards mode: http://jsfiddle.net/3s7Ly/1/

Comment: @TimDown: If it is a working version, would you mind editing that into your answer?

Comment: @nhahtdh: The code in the jsfiddle is exactly the same as in the answer. I haven't found the additional check to be necessary.

Comment: @TimDown Is this code still reliable for all browsers (namely Chrome, Firefox, IE)? Or better still, is there a version of this code snippet that doesn't rely on ActiveX objects?

Comment: @Bradley: `DOMParser` has now been [standardized](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#the-domparser-interface) so this code shouldn't get any less reliable. It works in current versions of all major browsers. It only falls back to the ActiveX stuff in old versions of IE; if you don't care about those then you can remove the ActiveX code branch, but it won't do any harm if left in.

Answer (score 7):

Consider using [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

Note that old JQuery's code (pre 2.x) is essentially identical to one proposed in the accepted answer and can be found at http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js, partial version below:

```
// Cross-browser xml parsing
parseXML: function( data ) {
    ...
    try {
        if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
            tmp = new DOMParser();
            xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
        } else { // IE
            xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            xml.async = "false";
            xml.loadXML( data );
        }
    } catch( e ) {
        xml = undefined;
    }
    ...
}
```

Starting JQuery 2.x code changed to skip ActiveX branch, if you still need it - use older version of JQuery or inline ActiveX parsing. Partial code from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js:

```
// Cross-browser xml parsing
parseXML: function( data ) {
    var xml, tmp;
    .....
    // Support: IE9
    try {
        tmp = new DOMParser();
        xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
    } catch ( e ) {
        xml = undefined;
    }
    .....
},
```

Comment: jQuery.parseXml can be pretty slow. I would suggest looking at the post from @TimDown

Comment: Maybe it was a year ago, but looking at the source code of jQuery (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js), I fail to see the difference from the TimDown's answer (omitting some error-handling logic).

Comment: @Zotov I've inlined your comment (post was rightfully downvoted as link-only, and your comment looked worth inlining rather than deleting the post).

Answer (score 4):

If you need to parse large XML documents that you may not be able to completely hold in memory, consider using a SAX style parser like this one: https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js/