# Get attribute value from xml by checking conditions

Tags: javascript

Following is my xml from where I have to get attribute value:

```
 <R a="1" b="2">
<I attribute1="" attribute2="some text"/>
<I attribute1="" attribute2="some text"/>
<I attribute1="0" attribute2="some text"/>
<I attribute1="0" attribute2="some text"/>
</R>
```

Here I've to check if `attribute1` is not null then I've to get value of `attribute2` from `I` tag.How to do this???
Please help...

Comment: In what language and what have you tried?

Comment: @Andreas:I have modified my xml in the post.Please check.Please ask me if you still don`t understand.

Comment: @IanKuca:I have a xml with me,from the xml I have to get attribute values as said based on the condition.I`m doing this in a js file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Here's a full X-browser working script that should do the trick. Again, replace the `getAttribute('attribute1')` by either arguments or return the DOM and take care of the rest. This code might look a bit complicated (it uses closures to be as lightweight as possible) but it should be quite sturdy and safe to use... as long as you don't declare another function called `parseXML` and you don't call this `parseXML` prior to it being declared.

```
var parseXML = (function(w,undefined)
{
    'use strict';
    var parser,i,ie,parsed;
    ie = false;
    switch (true)
    {
        case w.DOMParser !== undefined:
            parser = new w.DOMParser();
        break;
        case new w.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") !== undefined:
            parser = new w.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            parser.async = false;
            ie = true;
        break;
        default :
            throw new Error('No parser found');
    }
    return function(xmlString,getTags)
    {
        var tags,keep = [];
        if (ie === true)
        {
            parser.loadXML(xmlString);
            parsed = parser;
        }
        else
        {
            parsed = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
        }
        tags = parsed.getElementsByTagName(getTags);
        for(i=0;i<tags.length;i++)
        {
            if (tags[i].getAttribute('attribute1') && tags[i].getAttribute('attribute2'))
            {
                keep.push(tags[i].getAttribute('attribute2'));
            }
        }
        //optional:
        keep.push(parsed);//last element of array is the full DOM
        return keep;
    }
})(this);
var parseResult = parseXML('<r><i attribute1="" attribute2="Ignore This"/><i attribute1="foo" attribute2="got this"/></r>','i');
alert(parseResult[0] || 'nothing');//alerts 'got this' in IE and others
```

---

You  can [parse the XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var parsed = parser.parseFromString('<r a="1" b="2"><i v="" x="some text"/><i v="0" x="some important text"/></r>','text/xml');
var iTag = parsed.getElementsByTagName('i');
for (var i=0;i<iTag.length;i++)
{
    if (iTag[i].getAttribute('v'))
    {
        console.log(iTag[i].getAttribute('x'));//do whatever
    }
}
```

This snippet will log `some important text`, and not `some text`. That's all there is to it. If you need to store the `x` values, or return them just declare another variable:

```
var keep = [];//an array
//change console.log line by:
keep.push(iTag[i].getAttribute('x'));
```

This is assuming an `x` property will be set, if that's not always the case, an additional check can easily fix that. The full code will then look like:

```
function parseXML(xml)
{
    'use strict';
    var parser,keep,parsed,i,iTag;
    parser = new DOMParser();
    keep = [];
    parsed = parser.parseFromString(xml,'text/xml');//xml is the string
    iTag = parsed.getElementsByTagName('i');
    for (i=0;i<iTag.length;i++)
    {
        if (iTag[i].getAttribute('v') && iTag[i].getAttribute('x'))
        {
            keep.push(iTag[i].getAttribute('x'));
        }
    }
    return keep;//return array
}
```

Comment: Van:Thanks for the reply and answer.I`ll just check this and let you know.What do you mean by 'use strict'; here??

Comment: @user1495475: You're welcome. I've checked it in chrome, but you should check the link if your code needs to run on (older) IE versions. Also: don't forget to replace `getAttribute('v')` and stuff with the correct names, or turn them into parameters...

Comment: van:I tried the case,it`s throwing error like 'Domparser is undefined'.I checked it in google,old IEs` have this problem.Do you suggest me other way please???

Comment: I'll update my answer, giving you a full X-browser compatible sollution

Comment: @user1495475: made a couple of little mistakes in my first full version. This one works. [As you can see here](http://jsfiddle.net/d6cgf/)