# Tryfsharp.org - type providers?

Tags: f#, type-providers

Does anyone know what type providers are available on tryfsharp.org?

For example, I know that a CsvFile type provider is available by referencing:

```
#r "Samples.Csv.dll"
```

Additionally, there are:

```
#r "Samples.Hadoop.TypeProviders.dll"
#r "Samples.DataStore.Freebase.dll"
```

But what others can be used?  It would be cool if an XML or JSON type provider were available.  I can't seem to find any documentation on what dll's can be referenced in a script on tryfsharp.org.

Anyone have additional information on the matter?

Comment: There's also `"Samples.WorldBank.dll"` and `"Samples.WindowsAzure.Marketplace.dll"`.  I think that's it.

Comment: Oops, one more: `"Samples.Excel.WorksheetTable.dll"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ones you have noticed are all part of the "learning" section of TryFSharp.org .  The best way I've found to discover these is to look through the tutorials.

[Hadoop](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-science#hadoop)

`#r "Samples.Hadoop.TypeProviders.dll"`

[Freebase](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-science#data-analysis)

`#r "Samples.DataStore.Freebase.dll"`

[CSV](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-science#unlock-thousands)

`#r "Samples.Csv.dll"`

[Azure](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-science#azure-weather)

```
#r "System.Data.Services.Client"
#r "Samples.WindowsAzure.Marketplace"
```

[WorldBank](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-science#world-bank-health)

`#r "Samples.WorldBank.dll"`

[Excel.WorksheetTable](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/financial-computing#understanding-systemic-risk)

`#r "Samples.Excel.WorksheetTable.dll"`

A couple non-type providers (there might be ones I missed):

[MathNet.Numerics](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/financial-computing#analyzing-stock-markets)

`#r "MathNet.Numerics.dll"`

[MathNet.Numerics.Fsharp](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/financial-computing#analyzing-stock-markets)

`#r "MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.dll"`

[TryFSharp.org 's browser API](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-visualization#extending-tryfsharp)

```
open TryFSharp
Canvas.Show()
Canvas.Clear()

Canvas.SetContent "<h1>Try F# interop</h1>Try F# interop rocks!"

Canvas.RunJavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = 'New title!'"

let raphaelUndefined = Canvas.RunJavaScript "(typeof dojo === 'undefined')"
if raphaelUndefined :?> bool then
    Canvas.LoadScript "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"
```

(for this one please note `Canvas.LoadScript` which allows you to load javascript)

Not a file that needs to be loaded, but there is also:

[Samples.Charting.DojoChart](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Learn/data-visualization#quick-start)

`open Samples.Charting.DojoChart`

Comment: The Excel one is a type provider.

Comment: @kvb Ah, good call.  I fixed it, but feel free to correct anything else I've missed.

Comment: Although I did know about those and was specifically looking for an answer to a JSON or XML TypeProvider, your answer seems to confirm they do not exist. Thanks and good job on the detailed list.

Comment: Not F#, but since you can load javascript in the tryfsharp editor, you could find a javascript xml or json parser and write an F# wrapper for it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing