# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setProperty'

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code in the javascript

```
text = LxmlHttp.responseText;
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "application/xml");
xmlDoc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
```

I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setProperty'`

Please help me solve the issue.

TIA..

Hi Felix,
I have the below xml structure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response status="200">
  <ns3:op xmlns="http://xxx.com/details/" 
              xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.com/mgmt/" 
              xmlns:ns3="http://xxx.com/list/">
    <ns2:ntfs count="140">
      <ns2:ntf>
        <ns2:Nid>4687807</ns2:Nid>
      </ns2:ntf>
    </ns2:ntfs>
  </ns3:op>
</response>
```

I have to read this in IE 7, IE 8 , IE 9 , FF, safari and chrome

The namespace index may not be the same and might change.
I need to parse the xml independent of the namespace and browser.

I am trying to do this

```
var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(....);
xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", 'xmlns:ns3="http://xxx.com/list/"');
xmlDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
var op = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/response/ns3:op");
```

This works only in IE.
Please let me know how can i parse the xml in all browsers.

Comment: What are you trying to do? XML `Document` objects indeed don't have such a method.

Comment: Why do you think a method such as `setProperty` does exist? If you explain *what* you want to do, we might be able to help you.

Comment: Hi Felix,I have the below xml <?xml version="1.0"?>
<response status="200">
  <ns3:op xmlns="http://xxx.com/details/" 
              xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.com/mgmt/" 
              xmlns:ns3="http://xxx.com/list/">
    <ns2:ntfs count="140">
      <ns2:ntf>
        <ns2:Nid>4687807</ns2:Nid>
      </ns2:ntf>
    </ns2:ntfs>
  </ns3:op>
</response>

Comment: You can use the answer provided here for cross browser XML parsing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing, but there is nothing indicating that ``setProperty`` is working anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> This works only in IE

Yes. [`setProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms760290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a proprietary method in MSXML (actually I didn't knew IE did support XPath at all).

For the standard solution, see [MDN's article *Using XPath*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_XPath), favouring [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.evaluate). You should use feature detection to check whether it's available, and if not fall back to your [`document.selectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).