# Remove returns in XML string

Tags: php, javascript, xml

With simplexml_load_file... I've loaded an xml file. Now I want to process this file with javascript, so I created a string of it's content. Unfortunatly this string contains some returns so it can't be read. How can I get rid of these returns.

```
// this doesn't work because the return is not shown in the code, it just starts at a new line    
str_replace('\n','',$string);
```

I put in the xml as follows:

```
<?php
$results = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$resultsAsString = $results->asXML();
?>
//---
<script>    
    var xml = '<?= $resultsAsString; ?>';
</script>
```

And when I view the source it looks like this:

```
var xml = '<?xmlversion="1.0"?>
<element></element>
';
```

How do I remove the return after "?>" and after "/element>"

Comment: just note that `'/n'` is incorrect, use `"\n"`

Comment: Perhaps http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php would be os use.

Comment: Not sure if it works as I have not tested it. <script>var xml = '<?= $resultsAsString; ?>'; xml= xml.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");</script>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't forget that `\r` is another use of a newline character. Try something like this:

```
<?
$resultsAsString = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element></element>
';
$singleLine = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $resultsAsString);
?>
<script>
    var xml = '<?=($singleLine);?>';
</script>
```

Edit:
If you're looking to parse through the XML, may I suggest a look at this answer as well:

[Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing)

Comment: Thank you! I had in mind that I did tried that.. but apparently not in the correct way. Now it works :).