# How can I get a value from xml?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following xml:

```
<Order>
  <Moulding>
    <imgsrc>imgsrc</imgsrc>
    <width>1.13</width>
  </Moulding>
</Order>
```

I tried getting the Moulding width by:

```
moulding_width = doc.getElementsByTagName('Moulding')[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
```

However that is not working. How can I get the moulding width?

Comment: I'm not sure about the context you're working in, but this http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp might help, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by the context I'm working in? I've looked at all those links and I'm still having trouble.

Comment: @AllisonC With context, I meant: Where does the XML come from or where is it located? For which browsers does it have to work? Are you using any libraries such as, e.g., jQuery? I have included a simple example answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assume

```
var xml = "<Order><Moulding><imgsrc>imgsrc</imgsrc><width>1.13</width></Moulding></Order>";
```

Following, [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript) you can use (this requires jQuery)

```
var order = $.parseXML(xml).getElementsByTagName("Order")[0]
var moulding = order.getElementsByTagName("Moulding")[0]
var width = moulding.getElementsByTagName("width")[0];
var moulding_width = parseFloat(width.textContent);
```

or, using your method of node access

```
var moulding_width = parseFloat($.parseXML(xml).getElementsByTagName("Order")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent);
```

Note that `getElementsByTagName` gives you a list of the desired elements, and not their contents, this is why there is an additional `childNodes` compared to your approach.

If you're not using jQuery, you might consider something like (see http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp )

```
function parseXML(text) {
  if (window.DOMParser)  {
    parser=new DOMParser();
    return parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
  } else { // code for IE
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
    return xmlDoc;
  }
}

var moulding_width = parseFloat(parseXML(xml).getElementsByTagName("Order")[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
var data = "<Order><Moulding><imgsrc>imgsrc</imgsrc><width>1.13</width></Moulding></Order>";
var xml = $.parseXML(data),
$xml = $( xml ),
$test = $xml.find('width');

console.log($test.text());
```

I have checked this. You may also check this here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ecR6/

Check the console while you run the fiddle, you will find the log of value 1.13