# Get substring between tags in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an array of strings in following format.

`<data><summary>SUMMARY</summary><details>DETAILS</details></data>`

How do I get the content in between the `<summary> </summary>` tags using javascript?

Comment: What (precise) output do you want?

Comment: Edited the question, I need the content in between <summary> tags

Comment: The best way is to parse the XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649614/xml-parsing-of-a-variable-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var txt = "<data><summary>SUMMARY</summary><details>DETAILS</details></data>";
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
} else // Internet Explorer
{
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
}

console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('data')[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```