# Cross-browser support for DOMParser

Tags: html, dom, mobile, cross-browser, dom-manipulation

I'm using the DOMParser to manipulate AJAX-loaded html content before injecting it into the DOM. [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=DOMParser) state that current support is good, but doesn't go that far back - for IE with only partial support until version 10 and for iOS only full support in Mobile Safari from version 8.1. But in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752) the claim is made that it will work all the way back to IE6 (no mention here about mobile browsers). So, my question is: If one uses `window.DOMParser` or the ActiveX version `Microsoft.XMLDOM` what kind of coverage will one have? Will it cover IE back to IE6 as claimed in the linked post or is that too optimistic; and roughly what proportion of mobile browser users would one exclude requiring DOMParser support - pur in another way: is the mobile platform ready for DOMParser-supported applications?

Answer (score 0):

If you use something in the spirit of
`try { Microsoft.XMLDOM } else {window.DOMParser}`
You will be good as far back as IE 6. But three years later I hope you do not need that support anymore :)