# how to convert xml file into csv file in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, csv, demandware

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<current>
   <city id="1259229" name="Pune">
      <coord lon="73.86" lat="18.52" />
      <country>IN</country>
      <sun rise="2016-01-07T01:38:29" set="2016-01-07T12:42:53" />
   </city>
   <temperature value="27.49" min="27.49" max="27.49" unit="metric" />
   <humidity value="43" unit="%" />
   <pressure value="955.13" unit="hPa" />
   <wind>
      <speed value="2.65" name="Light breeze" />
      <gusts />
      <direction value="113.502" code="ESE" name="East-southeast" />
   </wind>
   <clouds value="36" name="scattered clouds" />
   <visibility />
   <precipitation mode="no" />
   <weather number="802" value="scattered clouds" icon="03d" />
   <lastupdate value="2016-01-07T06:25:45" />
</current>
```

I am trying to convert this xml into csv I have tried some thing like this but I am not getting any logic to convert data to csv format

```
       try {
            var file : File = new File(dw.io.File.IMPEX + '/src/weather.csv');
            var fileWriter : FileWriter = new FileWriter(file, 'UTF-8');
            var csw : CSVStreamWriter = new CSVStreamWriter(fileWriter);
            csw.writeNext(//here I want array of string data );
            csw.writeEndDocument();
            csw.close();
            fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch(e) {
            return PIPELET_ERROR;
        }
```

But I don't know how I can convert xml data into strings of array

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing for a way to parse XML into JavaScript objects.  Then you pick out the bits you want to put in your array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're using server-side JavaScript, moreover DemandwareScript, check XMLStreamReader class and E4X syntax. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML
E4X is EcmaScript For Xml, a proprietary syntax which is used for XML DOM access in Demandware.
You would need one more File object for reading the XML file.

Also your XML file is not "flat", so you would need to define which XML elements go where in the CSV.