# How to refresh a DIV instead of page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good, I come again, ask for your help, I have a code that provides me with data and it has a DIV.

```
<div id="teste1"></div>
```

What I wanted was to refresh the DIV and there is no whole page, I've been to see jQuery and AJAX code but they do connect to a PHP or HTML page and in my case the code is inserted in the homepage.

```html
<script>
//http://code.google.com/p/miniajax/
function $(e){if(typeof e=='string')e=document.getElementById(e);return e};
function collect(a,f){var n=[];for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){var v=f(a[i]);if(v!=null)n.push(v)}return n};
 
ajax={};
ajax.x=function(){try{return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')}catch(e){try{return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')}catch(e){return new XMLHttpRequest()}}};
ajax.serialize=function(f){var g=function(n){return f.getElementsByTagName(n)};var nv=function(e){if(e.name)return encodeURIComponent(e.name)+'='+encodeURIComponent(e.value);else return ''};var i=collect(g('input'),function(i){if((i.type!='radio'&&i.type!='checkbox')||i.checked)return nv(i)});var s=collect(g('select'),nv);var t=collect(g('textarea'),nv);return i.concat(s).concat(t).join('&');};
ajax.send=function(u,f,m,a){var x=ajax.x();x.open(m,u,true);x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4)f(x.responseText)};if(m=='POST')x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');x.send(a)};
ajax.get=function(url,func){ajax.send(url,func,'GET')};
ajax.gets=function(url){var x=ajax.x();x.open('GET',url,false);x.send(null);return x.responseText};
ajax.post=function(url,func,args){ajax.send(url,func,'POST',args)};
ajax.update=function(url,elm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.get(url,f)};
ajax.submit=function(url,elm,frm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.post(url,f,ajax.serialize(frm))};
 
function process(xml) {
  document.getElementById('teste1').innerHTML=xml;
  var title = document.getElementById('teste1').getElementsByTagName('song')[0].title;
  var name = document.getElementById('teste1').getElementsByTagName('Artist')[0].getAttribute('name');
  document.getElementById('teste1').innerHTML=' '+name+' - ' +title;
}
function checkXml() {
  ajax.get('/NowOnAir.xml',process)
}
window.onload=function() {
  checkXml();
  tId=setInterval('checkXml()',speed)  
}

</script>
```

Someone can help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is the data that you want to change to stored?

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is. can you explain better?

Comment: @Matt I added the code I want to do the refresh

Comment: Have you considered using an Ajax call and refresh the data in the div with the response of the call?

Comment: @CodeGodie I put the code, which I intend to do is refresh the div that provides code information

Comment: @Bigalow I've tested several codes, some do not work, others this div placed on other pages, which is not the case, because either DIV want the code estam both on the same page

Comment: It seems that you are just appending the contents of the xml file to the div, and not parsing it.

Comment: I dont see jQuery here

Comment: @leuanG This javascript retrieve information from an XML document, the code to me this working well what is missing is to get to refresh the DIV, so I came to ask your help

Comment: @CodeGodie 
https://jsfiddle.net/vyq1daeu/ I am trying here

Comment: Im sorry Andre, this code is very messy. Check out this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."_

Comment: @CodeGodie I can retire my question?

Comment: @DenizEng The XML file is this http://radiojoven.6te.net/NowOnAir.xml he calls because it can withdraw from there information

Comment: Can't make any sense out of what the specific problem is here

Comment: Is your app also on the same domain(radiojoven.6te.net) Andre Santos? Otherwise you'll get below error(on JSFiddle as well) and will need to use CORS 

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://radiojoven.6te.net/NowOnAir.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: @DenizEng I for example have this page http://radiojoven.6te.net/example.php where is the code I provide more DIV, and what I wanted was to refresh only the DIV and not to the page, I've had to search codes and more codes and can not find one I do

Comment: @charlietfl I am very grateful for the support the resolution, today I spent the day researching and testing codes and none gave

Comment: `tId=setInterval('checkXml()',speed)` here the speed variable is undefined Andre, you need to set it.

Comment: @DenizEng tid = setInterval ('check XML ()', 20000) something?

Comment: If `speed` is undefined it would throw error...are you seeing errors in browser console?

Comment: @AndréSantos yes. But that's not the only issue. You're receiving the XML response successfully, but then, you need to parse it instead of this line and then use the values.   `document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=xml;`

Here is a sample for parsing XML in vanilla JS:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing

Comment: @DenizEng Thank you, I could already do the refresh as intended, thank you again!

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you, I could already do the refresh as intended, thank you again!

Comment: Np. Is your problem resolved?

Comment: If you use the XML parser in the link that I provided above, the below will give you the song name, you can experiment to find other values:

`parseXml(xml).getElementsByTagName('Song')[0].attributes[0].value`

Comment: Also note that the tagname search is case sensitive, so you should have uppercase Song as per the xml file unlike your code in the question.

Comment: @DenizEng DIV already does the refresh as I wanted
tid = setInterval ('XML check ()', 20000)
Using your way also can access the title and song name

Comment: @DenizEng I so far had no problems with the code in question, provides exactly what is asked

Comment: Great, I've summarized my comments into an answer, please accept if it helped.

Comment: @DenizEng Done and thank you for the help and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your speed variable in window.onload handler is undefined, needs to be set to a number value. Secondly, you need to parse the XML response before traversing the elements. Link with sample:
[Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing)

You can use the xml parsing function above and the below code to get the song name and use the same approach to find the values of other elements.

`parseXml(xml).getElementsByTagName('Song')[0].attributes[0].value`