# Deserialize xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Suppose to have an xml like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Langs>
<dirs>
  <string>uk-fr</string>
  <string>uk-it</string>
  <string>uk-pl</string>
  <string>uk-tr</string>
</dirs>
<langs>
  <Item key="af" value="Afrikaans" />
  <Item key="ar" value="Arabic" />
  <Item key="az" value="Azerbaijani" />
  <Item key="ba" value="Bashkir" />
  <Item key="be" value="Belarusian" />
 </langs>
</Langs>
```

How can I get an array that contains the key of each item? Using javascipt?
An object as this:

```
  var array = [af,ar,az,ba,be]
```

Comment: You can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and then work with the document it returns. (I'm not at a computer now so can't try it out and give an example.)

Comment: Also there is [`jQuery.parseXML`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen But why use jQuery if you don't need it?

Comment: @gcampbell The DOMParser is an experimental feature and may not be supported everywhere.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen http://stackoverflow.com/a/7951947/6303733, http://caniuse.com/#search=domparser, compare with https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: @gcampbell thanks for bringing this to my notice

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen Thank you all, but how do I use jquery.ParseXML in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply.

Here's an example code on how to use [`jQuery.parseXML`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to solve the problem:

```
var xml_string = 'your xml string';

var output = $.parseXML(xml_string); // <-------- parsing using jQuery.parseXML

var array = []; // <----------------------------- array for storing the keys

// iterating over the elements where selector 'langs>Item' matches in the parsed XML
// and retrieving the key values and pushing them into the array
$('langs>Item', output).each(function(i, e) {
  array.push($(e).attr('key'));
});

// display the output
console.log(array);
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79ukduds/).