# Parse XML response in Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

I am a newbie to the world of `knockout JS`. Can anyone let me know how to parse the `XML` response returned from `SOA` call in below code.

```
//viewModel
```

Here the SOA service is called which is returning result. when statusChange value is passed.

```
someService.updateService(statusChange).then(function(result){
                        // parse result
                    });

//XML Response

<UpdateServiceResponse xmlns="*********">
   <result>data updated successfully</result>
</UpdateServiceResponse>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing)

Comment: IMHO the best answer is the first one in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)