# Access Attributes Values of Variable in XML Format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a remote Web service that returns to my JavaScript Web app the variable "DATA" defined in XML format.

An example of the data returned by a request would be:

```
<DATA><ID>1</ID><NAME>JOHN SMITH</NAME></DATA>
```

In JavaScript, how can I access the values of its attributes, i.e. the "1" as the ID and "JOHN SMITH" as the NAME?

For simplification,

```
(...)   

var DATA = <DATA><ID>1</ID><NAME>JOHN SMITH</NAME></DATA>;
var ID = ??; //HOW TO ACCESS THE VALUE OF ID IN DATA?
var NAME = ??; //HOW TO ACCESS THE VALUE OF NAME IN DATA?

(...)
```

Thank you!

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DomParser` and `querySelector`

```js
var xml = "<DATA><ID>1</ID><NAME>JOHN SMITH</NAME></DATA>";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");

console.log(doc.querySelector( "ID" ).innerHTML);
console.log(doc.querySelector( "NAME" ).innerHTML);
```