# JavaScript, Filter XML data coming from an external API

Tags: javascript, html

Basically i'm wondering if there's a way, with JavaScript, to filter XML data coming from a REST API V2 using GET, based on the the content contained in the tags.

I have an api key to the site.
https://"External Domain"/api/ver2/myXML.xml?apikey=MY_API_KEY

The plan is to use JavaScript to GET and filter the XML data and then view it in a HTML file.

Google'd around a bit but couldn't figure out what to use, SAX? DOM? fetch()?
Kind of lost...

Edit:
Can someone clarify if you can use the same methods to parse if you already have an  XML file with data, versus the data coming from a URL behind an apikey?

**To clarify, what i'm trying to parse is XML formatted data from a URL, not from a file.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604071/parse-xml-using-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Browser Javascript XML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing)