# How to parse this XML data..?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm working with [this XML](https://www.tekbuff.com/ebay-apps/logs/GetOrdersResponse_1596940374.xml) data, and I'm trying to loop through the Order elements within the OrderArray element.

I'm able to target the  elements using this:

```
$ebay_orders = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("Order");
```

This returns the number of Orders in the array, for example:

```
DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 2 )
```

It's been awhile since I've worked with XML like this, and I'm struggling to remember how I can get into these Order Elements and pull individual element values (ie. OrderID, OrderStatus, etc.)

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe these solutions will be of benefit on parsing the xml client side .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949752/cross-browser-javascript-xml-parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP XML, we can use Node Values to get Specific Elements. For e.g., I am trying to get OrderID for the first order in the following xml. You can fetch xml data from either hosted url or a sample file. Its upto your requirements. For demonstration purposes, I am going to use hosted file. The code can be:

```
$file = "sample.xml";
$url = "https://www.tekbuff.com/ebay-apps/logs/GetOrdersResponse_1596940374.xml";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); /* Replace $url with $file */

echo $xml->OrderArray->Order[0]->OrderID;
```

Here `$xml->OrderArray->Order[0]->OrderID;` will  retrieve OrderID like *19-05533-xxxx* for first key. Similarly, you can retrieve as many node values as you like.

Comment: Well, I'm not loading from a file in reality.  That was just a sample to look at.  I'm working within a script that's pulling this data back via an API, so the XML string is available directly as opposed to loading a file.  Is there something similar for that?

Comment: Ah, simplexml_load_string.  I'm going to play with that and then I'll accept your answer.  thanks.

Comment: sure. I have updated the answer in case you have xml stored in a file or a variable