# convert a JSON Schema to an XSD using node module?

Tags: json, node.js, xsd, node-modules

Does anybody know how to generate an XML schema(XSD file) from an existing JSON schema? using node js.
I found https://github.com/ethlo/jsons2xsd but it is based on java

Comment: looks duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367474/build-xml-based-on-xml-schema-in-node-js

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Jsonix (JSON interfaces for XML) is a JavaScript library which allows you to convert between XML and JSON structures. It generates JSON schema/ jsonix mapping from XSD. I want the reverse way(Take JSON schema and generate XSD).can you please suggest